# PHP inheritance and protected member visibility

Tags: php, inheritance

I've found something that appears to be a strange inheritance issue in PHP.

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

To me this means:
A can access the protected members of B if `A instanceof B` or `B instanceof A`.

However, if both A and B extend Foo, and Foo has a protected constructor which is not overwritten in B, then I can create an instance of B from within A. This does not make sense to me, because A is not an instance of B and B is not an instance of A. I can also call the protected method `$b->test()` from within A, which executes the method implemented in B. (If B does not redeclare `test()` then the implementation in Foo is executed.) To me this is even more strange because I cannot create an instance of B from within A if B directly implements a protected constructor. It seems strange that I cannot access a protected constructor (also declared in the parent class) but accessing a protected method (also declared in the parent class) is no problem.

Note that I do get the expected behavior when I use a class C which does not extend Foo. If I try to instantiate B from within C, I get a fatal error because I'm trying to access a protected constructor. If I add a public constructor to B it is possible to instantiate it (which is expected) and I still cannot access the protected method `test()` (this is also expected behavior). I expect the same behavior when using A instead of C.

Sample code which explains again:

```
class Foo {
    protected function __construct() {
        echo('Constructing ' . get_called_class());
    }

    protected function test() {
        echo('Hello world ' . __METHOD__);
    }
}

class A extends Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function testB() {
        // Both of these lines work
        $b = new B();
        $b->test();
    }
}

class B extends Foo {
    protected function test() {
        echo('Hello world Again ' . __METHOD__);
    }
}

class C {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function testB() {
        // Both of these lines cause fatal errors
        $b = new B();
        $b->test();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->testB();

$c = new C();
$c->testB();
```

I'm probably not seeing something, but I can't find what. Could anyone explain the behavior to me?

Comment: Very strange behaviour indeed.

Comment: Do you want an explanation of the rationale or of the implementation behind this behavior? Since this is PHP, there's a high chance that there *is* no rationale.

Comment: If there is a rationale, I would like to know what it is.

Comment: if you add a protected constructor in `B` the A::testB does not works. So I think that when A::testB try to call `B` constructor, it try to call the Foo constructor directly (because it missed in `B`). The Foo::_constructor is accessible from A, so it works (maybe it has no memory of child class). I don't tell here if it's right or wrong… but I think that happens this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access those methods because there is a declaration of them as protected in `Foo`, which is your parent and that gives you permission to access it. If you remove the declaration from the parent and declare the protected method in `B` you will get a Fatal Error.

This is reported as a bug in PHP https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50892

Comment: You can't call `new B()` from `A` if `B` overrides `__construct` even if `Foo` declares it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the bugs.php.net link. I did search there but was unable to find the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rationale about this, it has been reported 2 years ago: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52120

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think it's more strange that you can call inherited protected methods than the impossibility to call inherited constructors (which is expected behavior, imo)