# Php Indirect Inheritance?

Tags: php, inheritance

```
<?php

abstract class DadBuilder{

    abstract protected function __construct();

}

class Dad extends DadBuilder{


    protected function __construct(){

        print __CLASS__;
    }
}


class Child extends DadBuilder{

    public function __construct(){

        new Dad(); //Why this not throwing an error?
    }

}

$child = new Child();
```

Why Child::__constructor not throwing an error, since its not directly inherit from `Dad` class

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP inheritance and protected member visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745394/php-inheritance-and-protected-member-visibility)

Comment: very strange behaviour..

Comment: This is PHP. Nothing is strange. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am led to believe the answer is PHP Bug.  If I remove the `abstract` in front of `class DadBuilder`, I see that it *does* throw the appropriate error:

```
<?php
class DadBuilder {
    protected function __construct() {}
}
class Dad extends DadBuilder {
    protected function __construct(){
        print __CLASS__;
    }
}
class Child extends DadBuilder {
    public function __construct(){
        new Dad(); //Why this not throwing an error?
    }
}
$child = new Child();
```

Gives:

> Fatal error: Call to protected Dad::__construct() from context 'Child'
>   in /Users/dfarrell/git/provisioning/vagrant/singlestack/t.php on line
>   12

Thus I am forced to conclude that it's yet another issue with PHP's OO Implementation.  IT must be stumbling over the fact that `Dad` is implementing the same abstract function as `Child` and fail to recognize the scope.

<rant>One of many examples of the inadequacy of PHP, which is why I went from almost exclusively PHP to never using it except to answer stack overflow questions :)  Just switch to Ruby and all will be well :) </rant>

Comment: indeed its bug..its not do what its suppose to do as advertise in the php manual..switching to golang instead :)